# PHP Page Jumps Up and Down while loading html table elements from database

Tags: php, html

I'm loading tr and td elements into a table from a database using PHP, but when the table is loading, it jumps from the top of the page to the bottom of the page repeatedly until all the table elements are loaded. Is there any way for the page to stay in the same place without jumping to the table when the table is loading?

```
$result = $connection->query($query);
    if ($result) {
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td> data from table</td>";
                ...
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I put a lazy load on the page for now since it seems like there's no other solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to store your html in a variable and `echo` it when the fetching is done.

```
$html = "";    
$result = $connection->query($query);
    if ($result) {
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $html .= "<tr>";
                $html .= "<td> data from table</td>";
                ...
                $html .= "</tr>";
            }
        }
    }
echo $html;
```

Comment: There's less glitching, but the page still jumps up and down quite a lot. I have naked html on above and below this php code, and php at the top and bottom to connect to the database and close the connection. Do you know of anything else that could cause this?

Comment: how about loading the data asynchronously in another file, and then passing the results to your page when it has finished loading? Also I would open and close the database connection elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If your elements loaded from DB are used to build sth. like images, then this could lead to the problem because the browser does not know the size of the elements in advance. You can try to set the dimensions of the elements or a kind of a container as placeholder in advance.
Perhaps this approach is helpful, too: [Stop page jumping while images load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48281286/stop-page-jumping-while-images-load)